# Template literals working on other browser except IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am working on javascript and using "Template literals", which is working on the Chrome and Firefox, but it is not working on the Internet Explorer(IE).

```js
var a = 10;
console.log(`${a}`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template literals are ES6, and IE supports *very few* ES6 features. It doesn't support template literals.

For what you're doing, simply do `console.log(a)` instead:

```js
var a = 10;
console.log(a)
```

But if your real code is more complicated than that, you'll either have to concatenate manually, eg:

```
`foo${somevar}bar${somevar2}baz`
```

change to

```
'foo' + somevar + 'bar' + somevar2 + 'baz'
```

Or, a better option, if you like the syntax of template literals and don't like plain string concatenation, would be to integrate Babel into your build process to transpile ES6+ syntax (including template literals) to ES5 *automatically*:

https://babeljs.io/repl/

(Babel will not only transpile template literals, it'll transpile pretty much *all* of the newer syntax to ES5, like destructuring, arrow functions, `async`/`await`, etc - for larger codebases, it's pretty much essential, allowing the programmers to write in the latest and greatest version of the language while remaining compatible with ancient browsers like IE)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is if you already are using `lodash` to switch to its [`_.template`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#template) function which allows a lot more than just templating literal functionality and has `wide browser support`.

```js
var compiled = _.template('hello ${ user }!');
console.log(compiled({ 'user': 'pebbles' }));   // => 'hello pebbles!'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Tested in Chrome 65-66, Firefox 58-59, IE 11, Edge 16, Safari 10-11, Node.js 6-10, & PhantomJS 2.1.1" is just from their latest on their support page.